# should I do Access Control List serialized as json or database tables

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been researching on creating an Access Control List and there are a few things I've found. However, I'm not sure if one way is extremely overboard and another is far too simplistic.

So here it is:

Right now, how I have it set up is that in the users table i have a `permissions` field. This field contains JSON of all the permissions the user has. I was curious and wanted to know if there was a better way to do this and I have found structured databases that use separate tables for roles and permissions.

e.g.

```
role
-------------
id | name


permissions
-----------------
id | role_id | name


user_role
---------------
user_id | role_id
```

That's very basic, but the general idea.

My question is, which method is better. The tables approach seems a bit heavy with the joins and everything to get the permissions. However, when I look for the user, I can just pull out the JSON field and cache it... Or is there something fundamental that I'm missing?

Comment: I prefer the normalized table IMHO.

Comment: As this is primarily opinion-based, I’ll throw my two cents in: database tables. Index the columns properly and your joins won’t be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using native tables in place of non-native data structures when working with rational databases. Riding a bike down the interstate is an option but is it the best option?

**Efficiency**:
Modern database servers are able to cache the result of repeated queries so why waste resources in your app when the caching is already done for you. Most, at the least, offer a time-out cache where if the same query is produced moments apart the same result is returned(assuming values have not been altered for the result) from memory instead of requiring a DB read.

The larger your field-set becomes the more space a JSON string will take up on the file system, the slower that data will be to parse, and the more memory the cached result will consume. Using tables, the field-set will be far less resource consuming on the file system and enables you to request just the value(s) you need at that moment already formatted in a way your application understands. Where as with JSON, you retrieve a string that yet still needs more manipulation to be understood, containing not only the values you need at that moment but possibly quite a few values you do not need.

**Scalability**:
With a stored JSON string, if you wish to delete a no longer needed field or to add a required field you will have to spend quite a bit of processing power to adjust each item's data set. Where as with a table this can be done with a short query command. After such each time the server encounters an item with a field that is supposed to be deleted or missing a required field, that item's field will be adjusted in memory and the update will be scheduled for batch file system writing.

--

You state you are worried about joins being slow/costly to do, but assuming you are only requesting the data you need AT THAT MOMENT from ONLY the tables you need said values from the joins should be very minimum compared to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON way looks like Wordpress serialization, WP uses serialization to store options, take a look at this post, for a quick example:

[Working with serialized data in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319638/working-with-serialized-data-in-wordpress)

But it is used for options which IMHO are more or less irrelevant, options that have no need to be filtered or whatever, the only function is to provide the configuration of certain features. Let's say for unimportant things.

Permissions & roles are the kind of thing I would consider vital for any application, and the best way is to use the standard table approach. You could need new inserts and it's much easier, or to query who has certain permissions, and that's the magic of relational tables.

Comment: Ok, so what if I wanted to add an individual permission to a user outside of a defined role. Would I have to create another table and join everything in together? Would that cause more overhead?

Comment: If it is based on permissions, you would create a new row with the specific permission, if it is role-based, you would have to create a specific role too. Never new tables.